# is newspeak in close proximity to the present trend?

Tags: adverbs, language-evolution, pleonasms

I can't think of a way to question the use of the phrase "close proximity" without expressing an opinion or asking for one (and that applies both to the specific case of this phrase and wider implications one might like to propose).

If the question had a clear answer readily available, then it would be foolish to ask the question, except as a rhetorical measure to post a complaint about trends in language use (and that is not desirable in this forum).

If the question has no clear answer readily available, then opinion, expert or otherwise, would seem to be in order (but opinion is ostensibly not favored either on question or answer).

Under the circumstances, then, I withdraw the question (if that is possible).

Comment: Short answer: nope.

Comment: Doubleplus good question.

Comment: ...and I thought I had done a credible job of constructing a question not amenable to a short answer. Well, you certainly proved me incorrect (re short answer = nope).

Comment: I think we're all just getting over the shock of something so verbose being posted by someone with 1 rep; we're not quite used to that. :P I'm still parsing your question, to be honest.

Comment: So yeah, now that I've read and understood what you're asking, I don't think it's our responsibility. It is a crying shame that communication has taken that nosedive, but it wasn't our fault and there doesn't seem to be much we can do about it. Unfortunately I tend to have to dumb down what I say when conversing with people around me, as if I spoke the way I wanted to nobody would understand me.

Comment: So, is that bellyfeel or unbellyfeel you are expressing, John?

Comment: Plusunbellyfeel.

Comment: If what you're asking is whether it's a new thing for someone to spew forth a mass of egregiously contorted language, in long, tortuous sentences, using painfully ostentatious terminology, the answer is no.  Religious fanatics, politicians, and academic pedants have been doing this for easily two thousand years.

Comment: Concision is your friend, but attempting to dazzle your audience with verbosity can be counterproductive. Some listeners simply shut down after enough words over their vocabulary level.

Comment: See 'Thing Explainer' by Randall Munroe.

Comment: "Never use a sesquipedalian word when a diminutive one will suffice."

Comment: It is definitely ironic (and instructive) that my post is viewed as other than concise, precise prose.

Comment: It's the nature of people of merit to do their best and to see to the best in others.  Not all of us are members.  If you are a member, then you are responsible.  It's called giving.

Comment: A "concise" question is one where you have to toss in a few more words to meet the minimum question length.  "Precise prose" does not make average readers feel dyslexic due to the density of the text and the lack of an appropriate overarching structure.  There is more to writing than stringing words together.

Answer (score 6):

What is ironic is that you think that it is ironic that your post is "viewed as other than concise, precise prose."  Either that or irony doesn't mean what you think it does.  You have taken 472 words to propound the recurring banal thesis that careless speakers of English are debasing the language.  I direct you to Steven Pinker's *The Sense of Style*, where you will find the author going back decade by decade quoting authors despairing of the state of English.  He probably could have gone back to the dawn of writing.  I'm reliably told that the first writers were Sumerian scribes who used cuneiform to keep commercial accounts, but shortly thereafter took stylus to clay to complain about the writing style of their successors.

You say that you realize that language evolves, but you seem to have no clue as to how that happens.  Alas for you, language changes in spite of the efforts of the linguistically-responsible educated elite.  And embarrassingly for you, you chose to illustrate your point with the phrase "close proximity," claiming it an example of pleonasm.  The word *proximity* comes to us from the Latin *proximus* (the closest), but in English it means nearness.  And of course, some things are nearer than others, so it's common to qualify that nearness.  It's bad enough that you've based your evidence on the etymological fallacy, but the usage cannot illustrate  a current trend:  the *OED* cites "close proximity" from 1832.

You define *pleonasm* as "redundantly using more words than are necessary" and then invite us to enjoy the fact that you're intentionally using redundancy in your definition.  How droll.  But your prose is littered with unintentional redundancies: "by one means or another", "condense many words to few", "grammar and syntax".

Even aside from your self-congratulatory tone and the distracting parenthetical asides, you are a remarkably careless writer.  Consider

> a human is better able to watch and weigh his words when writing, than
>   speaking extemporaneously

Your reader expects a parallel construction:  better able to watch than [to-infinitive].  This is a clumsy way to express

> One can watch his words more easily when writing than speaking.

Or take

> it was a matter of how many people ... were using the phrase, rather
>   than identification

On the one hand a clause, on the other hand a noun.  And if you're going to lay claim to concision and precision, don't leave a comma splice in your prose.

I suppose it's churlish to complain about an impenetrable style, when it's your unevidenced often-irrelevant claims that are the problem:

- Orwell's newspeak was a fictional language pruned to make expression of dissent largely impossible.  It has nothing to do with changes to language by popular pressure.  By the way, Orwell's complaints about politicians was not that they engaged in "pleonasm", but that they used misleading language to excuse the inexcusable.  I've read George Orwell; I admire George Orwell; you're no Eric Blair.
- You're careful to distinguish between writing and texting, to no apparent purpose.
- You claim there are converging movements, one to reduce the complexity of human speech; the other to make some claim about "statistical ... speech recognition."  Is there evidence for either of these movements?  Note that the first is about natural language and the second is about computer-mediated language.  Is there evidence that the two topics are even related?
- A little research would have informed you that animal languages have their own syntax, although what relevance this topic has is beyond me.

But enough.  You say you're having trouble communicating with others.  Check the transmitter before you blame the receiver.  You ask whether you're missing the boat.  But that would require that you be near a port.

Comment: Wow. I've got to be careful only to post when you're asleep! +1 for the perceptive analysis and demonstration (or, rather, remonstration!) of what it's like to taste one's own medicine. BTW, obligatory xkcd comic to complement your citation of Pinker: https://xkcd.com/1227/ .

Comment: I'll second that "wow," but for different reasons, grin. deadrat has written well (the style complaints were sophomoric though), but completely missed the point of my post generally, and distorted or misunderstood the things I touched on briefly. I fear I may have misunderstood the purpose of this forum though and I do apologize for that. It is apparent I was barging into a social group like a bull in a china shop (though it feels more like the scene on pg. 33 of the script for the Idiocracy, the courtoom scene, grin).

Comment: @user5260 As for the "style complaints", you have been hoist on your own petard.  I merely pointed that out.  Or are you going to dispute the fact that your use of "close proximity" is inapt?  Or that you are guilty of the very sin you complain about?  As for your point "generally", are you going to deny in the face of the text that it's about the degradation of language and the responsibility of the elite to prevent that fate?

Comment: I guess I was more concerned about whether the capacity to recognize and communicate truth, or even to acknowledge that there is a legitimate concept of truth, is disappearing before our eyes. I didn't intend to nitpick language use so much as try to link the effect of a possible trend. When I say movement I am talking more about a zeitgeist-like (whew, I shouldn't be constructing something like this here, grin) spirit of imprecision or deception defused by the reduction of speech to canned phrases that get strung together when prompted. I don't think there is an applicable elite available.

Comment: @user5260 You have indeed misunderstood the purpose of ELU in particular and stackexchange in general.  It's not set up to be a discussion forum.    ELU is supposed to be a place where people exchange questions about specific topic in English grammar an usage and get in return definitive answers to those questions.  This is a possible reason for your 5:1, downvote to upvote ratio -- I am not one of the downvoters -- and the reason why your question is on its way to being closed.

Comment: If this be treason, make the most of it. (grin). Seriously though, I understand you are correct (in your most recent comment) and we shouldn't be turning this into a discussion forum unless it is focused on a definit question and answer (and at this point I've kind of lost that focus). So,I won't make any more comments, close or not. Thanks for the rousing discussion.

Comment: @user5260 Except that your OP doesn't mention truth.  It talks about "decreasing effectiveness", a reduction in "complexity", and something about statistical methods.  If you don't think there is an elite, why do you include yourself in its responsibilities?  This discussion belongs in chat, but alas!  participation requires 20 rep points.